# How to organize strings from Selenium in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe, whatsapp

**I am trying to extract data from whatsapp chatroom, but i am having trouble to send the data to a dataframe.

The code i have is:**

```html
chatroom = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_1_q7u')

pos= 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time','Msgs'], index=None)

for ol in chatroom.find_elements_by_class_name('message-in'):
    data = []
    msgs = ol.find_elements_by_class_name('woe4f')
    times = ol.find_elements_by_class_name('_1RNhZ')
    for msg in msgs:
        data.append(msg.text)
    for time in times:
        data.append(time.text)
    df.loc[pos] = data
    pos+=1
    print(df)
```

**The error returned error comes as "ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns" but the times i got the code to work, it brings me just the first elemnets in time and msg, i need all of them organized.

Noob trying to code here.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to drop somthing into a dataframe with loc you're going to have to make sure that the thing you drop in has the same dimensions as your df. Because you have 2 columns you need 2 things... You can achieve this by putting your times in a list and your messages in a list.

```
chatroom = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_1_q7u')

pos= 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time','Msgs'], index=None)

for ol in chatroom.find_elements_by_class_name('message-in'):
    msgs = [k.text for k in ol.find_elements_by_class_name('woe4f')]
    times = [k.text for k in ol.find_elements_by_class_name('_1RNhZ')]
    df.loc[pos] = [times,msgs]
    pos+=1
    print(df)
```

Comment: Sir, thanks for the help. It worked!! I deleted my previous comment because it was my mistake on scraping. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Quick question, how do i make the print(df) print just the final df with all rows? it is printing various dfs.

Comment: to get the last row use `print(df.iloc[-1])`

Comment: Nice! How can i remove the strings from the list after that? I need just the text on each cell but i got | ['msg´] | ['time'] | and the expecting result was | msg | time |

Comment: Not sure what you're asking but if you're just trying to get your lists back... `df.iloc[-1]['Time']` and `df.iloc[-1]['Msgs']`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The printed output from the whole DF comes in brackets and quotes. Each printed message and each printed time on the df comes like this: ['x'] ['12:21']. How do I make the output of each message and time be as plain text, without the brackets and quotes, like : X 12:21